# Play2 - Template -> incrementing

Tags: java, scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

How do I declare and increment a variable in play2? (in .**scala.html templates**)

Pseudo code:

```
@counter
@for(l <- list){
<span class="data-@counter">


</span>
@(counter += 1)
}
```

Comment: How do i declare such a variable?

Comment: Of course it is in a .scala.html template

Comment: That's little bit tricky, write us what exactly do you want to iterate, I'll try to find some sample

Comment: I edited my post, if this is tricky I could do it in java with a static function something like `@increment()` . I just thought it would be cleaner if I do this in the template itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you really need counter and incrementing? You can do this:

```
@for((l, index) <- list.zipWithIndex){
    <span class="data-@index">@l</span>     
}
```

Method `zipWithIndex` creates list of tuples.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's I was needed too ;) (read: that's the sample I was looking for)

Comment: Beautiful.  Just what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

to declare at template

```
@import java.math.BigInteger; var i=1
```

for increment in  template

```
@(i+=1)
```

Comment: expected class or object definition error throwed at 
```@import java.math.BigInteger; var i=1 
```