# Getting the index of the current loop in Play! 2 Scala template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In Play! 1, it was possible to get the current index inside a loop, with the following code:

```
#{list items:myItems, as: 'item'}
    <li>Item ${item_index} is ${item}</li>
#{/list}
```

Is there an equivalent in Play2, to do something like that?

```
@for(item <- myItems) {
    <li>Item ??? is @item</li>
}
```

Same question for the `_isLast` and `_isFirst`.

ps: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251504/play2-template-incrementing) is quite similar, but the solution implied to modify the code to return a `Tuple (item, index)` instead of just a list of `item`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, `zipWithIndex` is *built-in* feature  fortunately there's more elegant way for using it:

```
@for((item, index) <- myItems.zipWithIndex) {
    <li>Item @index is @item</li>
}
```

The index is 0-based, so if you want to start from 1 instead of 0 just add 1 to currently displayed index:

```
<li>Item @{index+1} is @item</li>
```

**PS:** Answering to your other question - no, there's no implicit `indexes`, `_isFirst`, `_isLast` properties, anyway you can write simple Scala conditions inside the loop, basing on the values of the zipped index (`Int`) and `size` of the list (`Int` as well).

```
@for((item, index) <- myItems.zipWithIndex) {
    <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        Item @{index+1} is @item <br>
             @if(index == 0) { First element }
             @if(index == myItems.size-1) { Last element }
             @if(index % 2 == 0) { ODD } else { EVEN }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Ok, in fact I didn't understand that the `zipWithIndex` was a *built-in* feature. I thought that I had to implement it on my controller or object. Thanks.

Comment: is there something like this for Scala (not Play)... just want to get my `i` back

Comment: Unfortunately this example is not incrementing properly. Iget this:
Item 30 is 
EVEN Item 5 is 
ODD Item 24 is 
EVEN Item 32 is 
EVEN Item 8 is 
EVEN Item 37 is 
Last element ODD Item 36 is 
EVEN Item 23 is 
ODD Item 34 is 
EVEN Item 22 is 
EVEN Item 6 is 
EVEN Item 3 is 
ODD Item 29 is 
ODD Item 35 is

How can i get a proper order like 0...10 ?

Answer (score 8):

The answer in the linked question is basically what you want to do.  `zipWithIndex` converts your list (which is a `Seq[T]`) into a `Seq[(T, Int)]`:

```
@list.zipWithIndex.foreach{case (item, index) =>
  <li>Item @index is @item</li>
}
```

Comment: yes, but I wanted to know if there is a built-in feature for that, instead of changing my own code...

Comment: @romaintaz, play 2 allows Scala expressions. Therefore, it comes down to whether scala has such a feature.