# Getting scala's template loop index in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to iterate in a playframework view, but without success for now. I have the following structure:

```
@if(list != null) {
    for(a <- 0 to list.size()/5)
    {
       //  some html, where I want to get the value of a
       for(b <- a*5 to a*5+5)  // here I want to use the a value again
       {
            some html
       }
    }
```

So my question is how to get the current index of the loop so that I will be able to use it.

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608334/getting-the-index-of-the-current-loop-in-play-2-scala-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should combine it in one for loop:

```
@if(list != null) {
    @for{a <- 0 to list.size()/5
        b <- a*5 to a*5+5}
            yield html
    }
}
```

And use option instead of `null` checking.
Also you can use `map` function to transform your list. See details in Play documentation - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates

Comment: The compiler doesn't accept that syntax... Also if there is that kind of loop, does it work the same way as I pointed out? Will it iterate through the b loop and then increment the a value?