# Initailzing variable in scala template

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-template

I have a simple code in scala template for Play

```
@( val i = 0){
.......
....

i => i+1; // incremental 
}
```

But the above code is not working any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** fetch the index of the iteration in Scala `for` loop, just `zipWithIndex` your collection:

```
@for((day, index) <- model.days.zipWithIndex) {
    <li>Day @index is @day</li>
}
```

like [described in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613877/1066240)

Answer (score 0):

Scala for loops are different to Java for loops. There is no loop index that gets incremented, rather successive values are taken from a sequence. So the loop you want is like this:

```
for(i <- 0 until 10) {
  ...
}
```

In a Play template, the above loop looks like this:

```
@for(i <- 0 until 10) {
   <p>number: @i</p>
}
```

The sequence in the above loop is `0 until 10`, which is actually a range. If you want to use `i` to look up a value in an array, don't do that. Get the elements directly from the array instead:

```
@for(element <- myArray) {
  <p>@element</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! got the point :)  The problem is I already have a look   like    @for( day <- model.days) {                                               }  I want to use value of i inside this something like 0 till length of model.days