# Receiving "not found: value" even the variable is define

Tags: scala, variables, playframework

I'm receiving `not found: value counter` even though the variable is defined.
Any help with this? I'm new with scala and everything is new to my eyes. Thanks

```
@{def counter = 0}
@for(atg <- Activity.groupContiguous(activityGroup)) {
  @if(!atg.isEmpty) {
    @views.html.activity.activityTypeGroup(atg, counter))
  }
  counter = counter + 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You code doesn't work because `@{def counter = 0}` doesn't define anything in the template scope and returns `Unit`. I don't know any convenient way to define mutable variable in the scala template, and this is actually discouraged.

The code could be easily rewritten using functional approach:

```
@for((atg, counter) <- Activity.groupContiguous(activityGroup).filterNot(_.isEmpty).zipWithIndex) {
  @views.html.activity.activityTypeGroup(atg, counter))
}
```

Comment: Thanks vitali, additional question. How can I increment counter value? I tried counter = counter + 1 but upon checking in the view the result became 0 = counter + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to other similar issue, you can solve it with `zipWithIndex` https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613877/1066240

Yo'll find there also other useful examples.