# Scala template: tags with increasing id

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-template

I am new to the play framework and scala templates. I have to loop through a map, and create an input tag for each element, with ascenting tag id.
So what I want to have in my resulting html is something like the following:

```
<li><input id="option1" type="checkbox"/><label for="option1">sometext</label></li>
<li><input id="option2" type="checkbox"/><label for="option2">sometext</label></li>
<li><input id="option3" type="checkbox"/><label for="option3">sometext</label></li>
```

The amount of inputs is dynamic, and their id needs to be ascending.

This is what I currently have, just looping through the map:

```
@for(c <- frage.getAllChoices){
    <li><input id="option1" type="checkbox"/><label for="option1">@c.getText()</label</li>
}
```

I tried using #define, but i can't change the value afterwards: it just prints the expression. And afaik creating a variable with "var" is not possible in play scala templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your case it should be an ID of the object not just incremented value, shouldn't it?

Anyway if you just need incremented value, you can use [zipWithIndex as showed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613877/1066240) i.e.

```
@for((c, index) <- frage.getAllChoices.zipWithIndex) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! :) Regarding the ID, this is a university project and we got a test class together with a framework, and the tests check for this exact naming.